# How to export a MySQL DB to MSSQL Database?

Tags: linux, windows, sql-server, mysql

The ultimate goal in this task to to take a complete database in MySQL and export it to MSSQL.  I was hoping to be able to do this with mysqldump.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you assure that there will be no data changes to the MySQL DB for the duration of the export? That opens up a lot of options.

Comment: Yes. Nothing will be changed on the MySQL database.  Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Document specificly addressing mysql to mssql 2005:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/c/8/ec8d5025-7ef7-4dcc-a9f3-9c297cf5350e/MigrateMySQLtoSQLServer.docx

White papers on migration:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=3f0f2a3f-dff9-49cd-8ea7-581aa7a303a4&displaylang=en&tm

This references mssql 2005, but should be very useful information and it is directly from microsoft.

There is a tool in mssql for major database migrations but, "Note: A Migration Assistant for migrating from MySQL to SQL Server is not available yet. "