# What tools are available to convert a MYSQL database to MSSQL 2005?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, sql-server, mysql

I found the following [tool](http://www.convert-in.com/sql2mss.htm) to convert a MySQL database to MSSQL.  We want to know if there is anything else available to do this before we go buying products.

We tried

```
mysqldump --compatible=mssql --result-file=dbname_mssql.sql dbname
```

no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: similar discussion http://serverfault.com/questions/44230/how-to-export-a-mysql-db-to-mssql-database

Answer (score 1):

If you have MSSQL Development edition or higher you already have the tool for you needs!

Checkout [This Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattm/archive/2008/03/03/connecting-to-mysql-from-ssis.aspx) on how to use SSIS with MySQL and SQL Server.  You can then use the data flow to manipulate the data from one server/table to another.

And of course see this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364545/ssis-and-mysql) discussion :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For simplier databases and a bit of manual work, you can dump mysql as CSV and then import into SQL Server using select ... outfile.

There is also a [tool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/migrate-mysql-to-mssql.aspx) on code project that apparently does this (I haven't verified whether it works).

Microsoft has a [guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966396.aspx) (from 2001, so it's a bit dated) about migrating from MySQL to SQL Server 2000.